# VueJS performance cost of $emit and Watchers

Tags: performance, vue.js

I've built a music app (using Vue and ToneJS) in which the user creates looping tracks which change in various ways according to user choices. This utilizes a rather complex set of scaling counter mechanisms. Having built the musical functionality, I am working on a "progress bar" which shows when the next transition is about to occur.

Currently, the way I am doing this is to calculate the total steps (each note is a 'step') needed and compare it to the progress of each counter (on the Vuex state). In terms of the code, that's a lot of mental overhead.

A better way to do this might be to use $emit to send out a 'tick' each time a step advances, which would be picked up by the component featuring the progress bar and compared to the steps needed. OR, use of a watcher on the component could detect the change and send a tick along.

BUT, I've already run into some timing performance problems with the app, and timing is critical for this. I'm a relatively new dev and don't yet understand performance well. So what I'm wondering is how 'expensive' is it to use `$emit`, or watchers? Since it would be attached to the 'motor' of the app, it would be called constantly. Is there any danger that this could gum up the gears?

Comment: Throwing events is not what's costly. The handling is. What can help is: a) Making sure you only fire the event when it's necessary b) you have cheap conditions in your handling (where you listen to the event) that stop the handling if it is not necessary. If I'm allowed to make you a suggestion: Go on and care about performance when it's actually a problem. Keep in mind that performance also depends on the computing power of the client that runs the application (e. g. your users computer).

Comment: I know it's a bit late but I tried to describe it for you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, you need to understand what their differences are!

**Emitting an event with `$emit` in `vue.js`:**

`Vuejs` is using the publish-subscribe pattern for emitting the events. [In software architecture, publish–subscribe is a messaging pattern where senders of messages, called publishers, do not program the messages to be sent directly to specific receivers, called subscribers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern).

Let's visualize this pattern:

Object1 will emit event `fooEvent`. Other objects might register a subscriber to this event, so whenever any `fooEvent` event emits the subscribers will be called.

This is how `vuejs` register subscribers ([source code on Github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/6fe07ebf5ab3fea1860c59fe7cdd2ec1b760f9b0/src/core/instance/events.js#L52)):

```
  Vue.prototype.$on = function (event: string | Array<string>, fn: Function): Component {
    const vm: Component = this
    if (Array.isArray(event)) {
      for (let i = 0, l = event.length; i < l; i++) {
        vm.$on(event[i], fn)
      }
    } else {
      (vm._events[event] || (vm._events[event] = [])).push(fn)
      // optimize hook:event cost by using a boolean flag marked at registration
      // instead of a hash lookup
      if (hookRE.test(event)) {
        vm._hasHookEvent = true
      }
    }
```

In a nutshell it just store them in an array `vm._events`:

`(vm._events[event] || (vm._events[event] = [])).push(fn)`

And this how it calls the subscribers ([source-code on Github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/6fe07ebf5ab3fea1860c59fe7cdd2ec1b760f9b0/src/core/instance/events.js#L118)):

```
    let cbs = vm._events[event]
    if (cbs) {
      cbs = cbs.length > 1 ? toArray(cbs) : cbs
      const args = toArray(arguments, 1)
      const info = `event handler for "${event}"`
      for (let i = 0, l = cbs.length; i < l; i++) {
        invokeWithErrorHandling(cbs[i], vm, args, vm, info)
      }
```

It iterates over all subscribers and calls them one by one in registration order.

So? It doesn't cost anything big!

**How watch works?:**

Well, it's a long story if we are going to talk about in the source-code but here is the short one:

Whenever you mark a property to be watched inside Vuejs, it runs a big code to watch its changes and schedule it inside a scheduler! **SO** `vue` understand the changes by pooling and checking if there is a change or not.

1. This is [how](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/33e669b22f69a1f9c9147528360fe0bba85534f0/src/core/observer/watcher.js#L26) it creates a watcher (every-time you mark an object to be watched, it creates a new `Watcher` object for it).
2. The `run` method inside a watcher will be [called](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/33e669b22f69a1f9c9147528360fe0bba85534f0/src/core/observer/watcher.js#L26) by the scheduler.
3. And how it [runs](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/22790b250cd5239a8379b4ec8cc3a9b570dac4bc/src/core/observer/scheduler.js#L164) them.

**So? It's quite heavy, isn't it?**

---

So the summary of the results and my opinion according to the codes and my personal experience:

Emitting an event isn't such a heavy thing, it's very very lighter than a watcher.

Comment: is this answer still valid for vue3?